# Remove all .fixed classes from force layout nodes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, force-layout

I have this **structure**, made by the d3.js force layout:

```
<div id="familytreecontentsvg">
<g class="nodes">
    <g class="node" transform="translate(625.2095978696435,404.7159479251927)" style="border: 3px solid red;"></g>
    <g class="node" transform="translate(549.3595414086468,461.0475336079573)" style="border: 3px solid red;"></g>
    <g class="node fixed" transform="translate(617.2898371986196,498.8572888164544)" style="border: 3px solid red;"></g>
</g>
```

And finally I would like to remove the .fixed classes from all nodes.

So triggering this event I have a button. To check if it's working I just for demonstrating added some css which worked. Somehow the remove class is not working. The fixed class is not removed:

```
$("#familytreeUnfixallbutton").click(function() {
    $( "#familytreecontentsvg .node" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );
    $( "#familytreecontentsvg .node" ).removeClass( "fixed" );
});
```

So How can I **remove all fixed classes** from the nodes?

### Current state

This one is working now:

```
d3.select('#familytreeUnfixallbutton').on('click', function(){
    d3.selectAll('#familytreecontentsvg .node').classed('fixed', false)
});
```

It removes the **fixed** class. But somehow d3 is not interested about this. It is still fixed =(

### Remaining question

I created a new question for the remaining issue: [Removing fixed classes does not properly remove them from the presetation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679156/removing-fixed-classes-does-not-properly-remove-them-from-the-presetation)

Comment: have you check if any errors on the console of the browser. its working on me your code

Comment: Jap, no errors and as I said the css edit is working properly. =/

Comment: can i ask the jquery library version you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that jQuery addClass/removeClass/toggleClass do not work with SVG elements. There is a [ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10329) on jQuery but it is closed and it 'won't fixed'.

You can use `d3.selectAll('#familytreecontentsvg.node').classed('fixed', false)` or the good old *[jQuery.attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)*. So your code should be like this:

```
$("#familytreeUnfixallbutton").click(function() {
    $( "#familytreecontentsvg .node" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );
    d3.selectAll('#familytreecontentsvg.node').classed('fixed', false)
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Was also just a copy paste mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Does not work: I have `d3.select('#familytreeUnfixallbutton').on('click', function(){
    d3.selectAll('#familytreecontentsvg.node').classed('fixed', false)
});` now

Comment: don't change the click listener. I edited my answer with the full solution.

Comment: Still the same. Border is added but the fixed class is not gone. Mhh I think I create a jsfiddle for that.

Comment: a jsFiddle will be ideal

Comment: Your selector is wrong in that jsFiddle. Towards the end, it should be     `d3.selectAll('#main-right .node')`, rather than  `d3.selectAll('#main-right.node')`. (there is a space in `.node`)

Comment: Tested with and without. No chance =/

Comment: I have updated the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d2gjxy7n/9/ If you see, when there is a class fixed, it gets removed when you click the button

Comment: Indeed in your fiddle is working. And now it's removing the fixed class also on my project. But it is still fixed when I move other nodes. So how can I properly unfix them?

Comment: That's a different question... you can accept the answer and 'Ask' another question addressing that specific problem

Comment: Alright =) Here we go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679156/removing-fixed-classes-does-not-properly-remove-them-from-the-presetation

Answer (score 1):

What 'skay' said is correct, just make sure you're selecting the correct thing otherwise it won't work. 
In my opinion I'd give the nodes ID's and select them by ID then remove the class you want.

```
nodes.attr("id", function(d,i){ return "nodes" + i;}); //unique ID
//or
nodes.attr("id", "nodes"); //same ID

//selecting using the second way of adding ID
    d3.select("#nodes").classed("fixed", false); //remove fixed class
```

If you wish to add a class, just as simple :

```
d3.select("#nodes").classed("fixed", true); //add fixed class
```

Comment: I have answered the second question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679156/removing-fixed-classes-does-not-properly-remove-them-from-the-presetation/28679220#28679220

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code

```js
$("#familytreeUnfixallbutton").click(function() {
    $( "#familytreecontentsvg .node" ).each(function(){
       $(this).removeClass("fixed");
     });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="familytreecontentsvg">
<g class="nodes">
    <g class="node" transform="translate(625.2095978696435,404.7159479251927)" style="border: 3px solid red;"></g>
    <g class="node" transform="translate(549.3595414086468,461.0475336079573)" style="border: 3px solid red;"></g>
    <g class="node fixed" transform="translate(617.2898371986196,498.8572888164544)" style="border: 3px solid red;"></g>
</g>
  <input id="familytreeUnfixallbutton" value="Test Button" type="button" style="float:right; margin-right:100px;" Text="Test Button" />
```

Comment: Please check it's working for me. I have updated code on page load not on button click because I don't have button click event.

Comment: Mhh well can you get it working here maybe? http://jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/d2gjxy7n/7/

Comment: Sorry I don't have access for jsfiddle in my office.

Comment: Try with apply setTimeout on button click one more thing what version of JQuery you are on?

Comment: Why setTimeout? What should that be different then? I have` <script src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71496/discussion-between-yogesh-sharma-and-kwoxer).

Comment: Please check now I have updated code now on button click it's working.

Comment: For setTimeout, just for testing only