# Removing fixed classes does not properly remove them from the presetation

Tags: jquery, class, d3.js, nodes, fixed

Concerning: [Remove all .fixed classes from force layout nodes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669830/remove-all-fixed-classes-from-force-layout-nodes-with-jquery)

I can remove the fixed classes now. But the **nodes are still fixed** in the view.

So simply removing the class is not enough I believe. I didn't find any help in the docs of D3 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you wanting to go back to the force layout ?

Its because you have only removed the class not the actual fixed property.

Try this :

```
 d3.selectAll(".node") //select your node here
    .each(function(d){d.fixed = false;})
    .classed("fixed", false);
 force.start(); //-bring the force layout back
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/d2gjxy7n/11/

Comment: Works properly. But `force.start()` is not needed. At least for my case. Thank you. So I also had to go into the object and set them to `fixed = false`. That's logical. So easy =)

Comment: yeah, in my code I can select multiple nodes and drag them at once, so I needed to use force.stop(); that's why I had to start it again :) And yeah it's simple once you know how :)) good luck